# 'storyboardName' resource not found. Call XAML to C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard, quaternions

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question but I have only 11 reputations and I can't comment to other questions or do anything so I have to ask again.

I have this code from here: [code - Quaternion Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.quaternion(v=vs.110).aspx) and I want to add it on my project but It can't find the "QuaternionWText", " endQuaternion", "myQuaternionRotation3D" and "myRotateTransform3D".

Then I found this part of code from another question that was asked here:

XAML code

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="TheStoryboard" x:Name="storyboardName">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                         To="500"
                         Duration="0:0:0.10" />
           <DoubleAnimation From="0" 
                            To="1" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.25"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="MainFrame" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
    </Storyboard>
```

C# code

```
 Storyboard story = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("storyboardName");
            this.BeginStoryboard(story);
```

but when I run the code I get the error that 'storyboardName' resource not found.

My class for the XAML name is XplorerMainWindow.xaml, and the cs project name is XplorerMainWindow.xaml.cs. The name of the class where I want to add the above C# code, is named "  private void CreateWorker()". All the x:names on my XAML code are: "MainFrame", "DockingManager", "MainPanel", "MainDocPanel", "DrawingControl".

What I am trying to do is that I have a 3D model and I want to rotate it using quaternion. But all the examples that I found Use XAML but I always get the error that they cant find the resource which should be called from XAML. So Am I doing anything wrong with the target Name or something? Shall I change anything according to my classes and names? shall I add the c# code somewhere else instead of the CreatWorker()?

EDIT

```
<Window x:Class="XbimXplorer.XplorerMainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:xbim="http://schemas.Xbim.com/Presentation"
     xmlns:xbimView="clr-namespace:Xbim.IO.ViewModels;assembly=Xbim.IO"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XbimXplorer"
xmlns:pt="clr-namespace:PropertyTools.Wpf;assembly=PropertyTools.Wpf" 
xmlns:avalonDock="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
Title="Xbim Xplorer" Height="600" Width="800" 
x:Name="MainWindow"
    Icon="xBIM.ico">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ModelProvider"  IsInitialLoadEnabled="False" ></ObjectDataProvider>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xbimView:XbimModelViewModel}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ....
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xbimView:SpatialViewModel}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <....
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xbimView:ContainedElementsViewModel}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               .....
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xbimView:IfcProductModelView}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                .....
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

 //Here is the Storyboard

      <Storyboard x:Key="TheStoryboard" x:Name="storyboardName">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                     To="500"
                     Duration="0:0:0.10" />
        <DoubleAnimation From="0" 
                        To="1" 
                        Duration="0:0:0.25"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MainFrame" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="   (FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
    </Storyboard>

</Window.Resources>
```

And this is how I call it in XplorerMainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 private void SpatialControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Storyboard story = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("storyboardName");
        this.BeginStoryboard(story);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you try to get that `Storyboard` from another window. It mean, if you would like to get some resource in code-behind you should place that resource in the current window.
For more information go to [How to: Retrieve Resources in Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/bb514687%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

PS

Here is an example of declaring and using resources:

```
<Window x:Class="XbimXplorer.XplorerMainWindow" ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="TheStoryboard" />
    </Window.Resources>
...
</Window>
```

And than you could get this storyboard in .cs

Comment: So my XMAL starts like that "<Window x:Class="XbimXplorer.XplorerMainWindow"" and my .cs like that: namespace XbimXplorer
{
    public partial class XplorerMainWindow : IXbimXplorerPluginMasterWindow{....)

So doesn't that mean that I call it from the correct window?

Comment: It is hard to help you because I do not see entire XAML code.
Make sure that this storyboard is placed in resources of your window.
PS
I added an example into my post above.

Comment: I have edited my question and I added the XAML part that I think you need to know, and the .cs class where I call the Storyboard. I do have the Storyboard in Resources but I still get this when I double click on the model  "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: 'storyboardName' resource not found." I can't find what I am doing wrong :/

Comment: OK. I have just realized a problem. You have to use a key to get resources instead of name. Her is an example `this.Resources["TheStoryboard"]`

Comment: Yep that was it. Problem solved. Thanks.
This is what I did 
**Storyboard story;
story = (Storyboard)this.Resources["TheStoryboard"];**